# Mediapipe not running even after installation MacBook M1

Tags: python, apple-m1, mediapipe

I am trying to get MediaPipe Pose estimation running on VS code on my MacBook M1. I installed it using `pip install mediapipe-silicon` and it installed successfully.
I am running the generic MediaPipe code without modifications:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with mp_pose.Pose(
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
  while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
      # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
      continue

    # To improve performance, optionally mark the image as not writeable to
    # pass by reference.
    image.flags.writeable = False
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = pose.process(image)

    # Draw the pose annotation on the image.
    image.flags.writeable = True
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
        image,
        results.pose_landmarks,
        mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
        landmark_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style())
    # Flip the image horizontally for a selfie-view display.
    cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Pose', cv2.flip(image, 1))
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
      break
cap.release()
```

When I run this code, the webcam light turns on for 2 seconds and then off. I do not get a pop up window to see the webcam. I also get this on the terminal:

```
objc[90068]: Class CaptureDelegate is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-310-darwin.so (0x10abe6458) and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_videoio.3.4.16.dylib (0x10d4cc860). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[90068]: Class CVWindow is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-310-darwin.so (0x10abe64a8) and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x10c430a68). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[90068]: Class CVView is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-310-darwin.so (0x10abe64d0) and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x10c430a90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[90068]: Class CVSlider is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-310-darwin.so (0x10abe64f8) and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x10c430ab8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:335] Error parsing text-format mediapipe.CalculatorGraphConfig: 22:9: Message type "mediapipe.CalculatorOptions" has no field named "ext".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jana/Documents/GitHub/AS2-MLC-Project/multi_pose.py", line 7, in <module>
    with mp_pose.Pose(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solutions/pose.py", line 146, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 247, in __init__
    self._graph = calculator_graph.CalculatorGraph(
RuntimeError: Failed to parse: node {
  calculator: "ImagePropertiesCalculator"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_CPU:image"
  output_stream: "SIZE:image_size"
}
node {
  calculator: "PreviousLoopbackCalculator"
  input_stream: "MAIN:image"
  input_stream: "LOOP:pose_rect_from_landmarks"
  output_stream: "PREV_LOOP:prev_pose_rect_from_landmarks"
  input_stream_info {
    tag_index: "LOOP"
    back_edge: true
  }
}
node {
  calculator: "GateCalculator"
  input_stream: "prev_pose_rect_from_landmarks"
  output_stream: "gated_prev_pose_rect_from_landmarks"
  input_side_packet: "ALLOW:use_prev_landmarks"
  options {
    ext {
      allow: true
    }
  }
}
node {
  calculator: "PacketPresenceCalculator"
  input_stream: "PACKET:gated_prev_pose_rect_from_landmarks"
  output_stream: "PRESENCE:prev_pose_rect_from_landmarks_is_present"
}
node {
  calculator: "GateCalculator"
  input_stream: "image"
  input_stream: "image_size"
  input_stream: "DISALLOW:prev_pose_rect_from_landmarks_is_present"
  output_stream: "image_for_pose_detection"
  output_stream: "image_size_for_pose_detection"
  options {
    ext {
      empty_packets_as_allow: true
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posedetectioncpu__ImageToTensorCalculator"
  calculator: "ImageToTensorCalculator"
  input_stream: "IMAGE:image_for_pose_detection"
  output_stream: "TENSORS:posedetectioncpu__input_tensors"
  output_stream: "LETTERBOX_PADDING:posedetectioncpu__letterbox_padding"
  options {
    ext {
      output_tensor_width: 224
      output_tensor_height: 224
      keep_aspect_ratio: true
      output_tensor_float_range {
        min: -1
        max: 1
      }
      gpu_origin: TOP_LEFT
      border_mode: BORDER_ZERO
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posedetectioncpu__SsdAnchorsCalculator"
  calculator: "SsdAnchorsCalculator"
  output_side_packet: "posedetectioncpu__anchors"
  options {
    ext {
      input_size_width: 224
      input_size_height: 224
      min_scale: 0.1484375
      max_scale: 0.75
      anchor_offset_x: 0.5
      anchor_offset_y: 0.5
      num_layers: 5
      strides: 8
      strides: 16
      strides: 32
      strides: 32
      strides: 32
      aspect_ratios: 1
      fixed_anchor_size: true
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__ImagePropertiesCalculator"
  calculator: "ImagePropertiesCalculator"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_CPU:image"
  output_stream: "SIZE:poselandmarkbyroicpu__image_size"
}
node {
  name: "posedetectioncpu__inferencecalculator__posedetectioncpu__InferenceCalculator"
  calculator: "InferenceCalculatorCpu"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:posedetectioncpu__input_tensors"
  output_stream: "TENSORS:posedetectioncpu__detection_tensors"
  options {
    ext {
      model_path: "mediapipe/modules/pose_detection/pose_detection.tflite"
      delegate {
        xnnpack {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posedetectioncpu__TensorsToDetectionsCalculator"
  calculator: "TensorsToDetectionsCalculator"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:posedetectioncpu__detection_tensors"
  output_stream: "DETECTIONS:posedetectioncpu__unfiltered_detections"
  input_side_packet: "ANCHORS:posedetectioncpu__anchors"
  options {
    ext {
      num_classes: 1
      num_boxes: 2254
      num_coords: 12
      keypoint_coord_offset: 4
      num_keypoints: 4
      num_values_per_keypoint: 2
      box_coord_offset: 0
      x_scale: 224
      y_scale: 224
      w_scale: 224
      h_scale: 224
      reverse_output_order: true
      sigmoid_score: true
      score_clipping_thresh: 100
      min_score_thresh: 0.5
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posedetectioncpu__NonMaxSuppressionCalculator"
  calculator: "NonMaxSuppressionCalculator"
  input_stream: "posedetectioncpu__unfiltered_detections"
  output_stream: "posedetectioncpu__filtered_detections"
  options {
    ext {
      min_suppression_threshold: 0.3
      overlap_type: INTERSECTION_OVER_UNION
      algorithm: WEIGHTED
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posedetectioncpu__DetectionLetterboxRemovalCalculator"
  calculator: "DetectionLetterboxRemovalCalculator"
  input_stream: "DETECTIONS:posedetectioncpu__filtered_detections"
  input_stream: "LETTERBOX_PADDING:posedetectioncpu__letterbox_padding"
  output_stream: "DETECTIONS:pose_detections"
}
node {
  calculator: "SplitDetectionVectorCalculator"
  input_stream: "pose_detections"
  output_stream: "pose_detection"
  options {
    ext {
      ranges {
        begin: 0
        end: 1
      }
      element_only: true
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posedetectiontoroi__AlignmentPointsRectsCalculator"
  calculator: "AlignmentPointsRectsCalculator"
  input_stream: "DETECTION:pose_detection"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_SIZE:image_size_for_pose_detection"
  output_stream: "NORM_RECT:posedetectiontoroi__raw_roi"
  options {
    ext {
      rotation_vector_start_keypoint_index: 0
      rotation_vector_end_keypoint_index: 1
      rotation_vector_target_angle_degrees: 90
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posedetectiontoroi__RectTransformationCalculator"
  calculator: "RectTransformationCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECT:posedetectiontoroi__raw_roi"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_SIZE:image_size_for_pose_detection"
  output_stream: "pose_rect_from_detection"
  options {
    ext {
      scale_x: 1.25
      scale_y: 1.25
      square_long: true
    }
  }
}
node {
  calculator: "MergeCalculator"
  input_stream: "pose_rect_from_detection"
  input_stream: "gated_prev_pose_rect_from_landmarks"
  output_stream: "pose_rect"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__ImageToTensorCalculator"
  calculator: "ImageToTensorCalculator"
  input_stream: "IMAGE:image"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECT:pose_rect"
  output_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__input_tensors"
  output_stream: "LETTERBOX_PADDING:poselandmarkbyroicpu__letterbox_padding"
  output_stream: "MATRIX:poselandmarkbyroicpu__transformation_matrix"
  options {
    ext {
      output_tensor_width: 256
      output_tensor_height: 256
      keep_aspect_ratio: true
      output_tensor_float_range {
        min: 0
        max: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__InverseMatrixCalculator"
  calculator: "InverseMatrixCalculator"
  input_stream: "MATRIX:poselandmarkbyroicpu__transformation_matrix"
  output_stream: "MATRIX:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__inverse_transformation_matrix"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__SwitchDemuxCalculator"
  calculator: "SwitchDemuxCalculator"
  input_side_packet: "SELECT:model_complexity"
  options {
    ext {
      select: 1
    }
  }
  input_stream_handler {
    input_stream_handler: "ImmediateInputStreamHandler"
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__ConstantSidePacketCalculator_1"
  calculator: "ConstantSidePacketCalculator"
  output_side_packet: "PACKET:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__c0__poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  options {
    ext {
      packet {
        string_value: "mediapipe/modules/pose_landmark/pose_landmark_lite.tflite"
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__ConstantSidePacketCalculator_2"
  calculator: "ConstantSidePacketCalculator"
  output_side_packet: "PACKET:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__c1__poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  options {
    ext {
      packet {
        string_value: "mediapipe/modules/pose_landmark/pose_landmark_full.tflite"
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__ConstantSidePacketCalculator_3"
  calculator: "ConstantSidePacketCalculator"
  output_side_packet: "PACKET:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__c2__poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  options {
    ext {
      packet {
        string_value: "mediapipe/modules/pose_landmark/pose_landmark_heavy.tflite"
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__SwitchMuxCalculator"
  calculator: "SwitchMuxCalculator"
  input_side_packet: "SELECT:model_complexity"
  input_side_packet: "C0__PACKET:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__c0__poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  input_side_packet: "C1__PACKET:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__c1__poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  input_side_packet: "C2__PACKET:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__switchcontainer__c2__poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  output_side_packet: "PACKET:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  options {
    ext {
      select: 1
    }
  }
  input_stream_handler {
    input_stream_handler: "ImmediateInputStreamHandler"
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__LocalFileContentsCalculator"
  calculator: "LocalFileContentsCalculator"
  input_side_packet: "FILE_PATH:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_path"
  output_side_packet: "CONTENTS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_blob"
  options {
    ext {
      text_mode: false
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__TfLiteModelCalculator"
  calculator: "TfLiteModelCalculator"
  input_side_packet: "MODEL_BLOB:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarkmodelloader__model_blob"
  output_side_packet: "MODEL:poselandmarkbyroicpu__model"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__inferencecalculator__poselandmarkbyroicpu__InferenceCalculator"
  calculator: "InferenceCalculatorCpu"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__input_tensors"
  output_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__output_tensors"
  input_side_packet: "MODEL:poselandmarkbyroicpu__model"
  options {
    ext {
      delegate {
        xnnpack {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__SplitTensorVectorCalculator"
  calculator: "SplitTensorVectorCalculator"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__output_tensors"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__landmark_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__pose_flag_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__segmentation_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__heatmap_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__world_landmark_tensor"
  options {
    ext {
      ranges {
        begin: 0
        end: 1
      }
      ranges {
        begin: 1
        end: 2
      }
      ranges {
        begin: 2
        end: 3
      }
      ranges {
        begin: 3
        end: 4
      }
      ranges {
        begin: 4
        end: 5
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__TensorsToFloatsCalculator"
  calculator: "TensorsToFloatsCalculator"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__pose_flag_tensor"
  output_stream: "FLOAT:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__pose_presence_score"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ThresholdingCalculator"
  calculator: "ThresholdingCalculator"
  input_stream: "FLOAT:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__pose_presence_score"
  output_stream: "FLAG:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__pose_presence"
  options {
    ext {
      threshold: 0.5
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__GateCalculator_1"
  calculator: "GateCalculator"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__landmark_tensor"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__world_landmark_tensor"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__segmentation_tensor"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__heatmap_tensor"
  input_stream: "ALLOW:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__pose_presence"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_landmark_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_world_landmark_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_segmentation_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_heatmap_tensor"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__TensorsToLandmarksCalculator_1"
  calculator: "TensorsToLandmarksCalculator"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_landmark_tensor"
  output_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__raw_landmarks"
  options {
    ext {
      num_landmarks: 39
      input_image_width: 256
      input_image_height: 256
      visibility_activation: SIGMOID
      presence_activation: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__RefineLandmarksFromHeatmapCalculator"
  calculator: "RefineLandmarksFromHeatmapCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__raw_landmarks"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_heatmap_tensor"
  output_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__all_landmarks"
  options {
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__SplitNormalizedLandmarkListCalculator"
  calculator: "SplitNormalizedLandmarkListCalculator"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__all_landmarks"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_landmarks"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_auxiliary_landmarks"
  options {
    ext {
      ranges {
        begin: 0
        end: 33
      }
      ranges {
        begin: 33
        end: 35
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__TensorsToLandmarksCalculator_2"
  calculator: "TensorsToLandmarksCalculator"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_world_landmark_tensor"
  output_stream: "LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__all_world_landmarks"
  options {
    ext {
      num_landmarks: 39
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__SplitLandmarkListCalculator"
  calculator: "SplitLandmarkListCalculator"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__all_world_landmarks"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__world_landmarks_without_visibility"
  options {
    ext {
      ranges {
        begin: 0
        end: 33
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__VisibilityCopyCalculator"
  calculator: "VisibilityCopyCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS_FROM:poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_landmarks"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS_TO:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__world_landmarks_without_visibility"
  output_stream: "LANDMARKS_TO:poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_world_landmarks"
  options {
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__GateCalculator_2"
  calculator: "GateCalculator"
  input_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__ensured_segmentation_tensor"
  output_stream: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__enabled_segmentation_tensor"
  input_side_packet: "ALLOW:enable_segmentation"
  options {
    ext {
      allow: false
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__TensorsToSegmentationCalculator"
  calculator: "TensorsToSegmentationCalculator"
  input_stream: "TENSORS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__tensorstoposelandmarksandsegmentation__enabled_segmentation_tensor"
  output_stream: "MASK:poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_segmentation_mask"
  options {
    ext {
      gpu_origin: TOP_LEFT
      activation: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__LandmarkLetterboxRemovalCalculator_1"
  calculator: "LandmarkLetterboxRemovalCalculator"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_landmarks"
  input_stream: "LETTERBOX_PADDING:poselandmarkbyroicpu__letterbox_padding"
  output_stream: "LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__adjusted_landmarks"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__LandmarkLetterboxRemovalCalculator_2"
  calculator: "LandmarkLetterboxRemovalCalculator"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_auxiliary_landmarks"
  input_stream: "LETTERBOX_PADDING:poselandmarkbyroicpu__letterbox_padding"
  output_stream: "LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__adjusted_auxiliary_landmarks"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__LandmarkProjectionCalculator_1"
  calculator: "LandmarkProjectionCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__adjusted_landmarks"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECT:pose_rect"
  output_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:unfiltered_pose_landmarks"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__LandmarkProjectionCalculator_2"
  calculator: "LandmarkProjectionCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__adjusted_auxiliary_landmarks"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECT:pose_rect"
  output_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:unfiltered_auxiliary_landmarks"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkfiltering__LandmarksToDetectionCalculator"
  calculator: "LandmarksToDetectionCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:unfiltered_auxiliary_landmarks"
  output_stream: "DETECTION:poselandmarkfiltering__aux_detection"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkfiltering__AlignmentPointsRectsCalculator"
  calculator: "AlignmentPointsRectsCalculator"
  input_stream: "DETECTION:poselandmarkfiltering__aux_detection"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_SIZE:image_size"
  output_stream: "NORM_RECT:poselandmarkfiltering__roi"
  options {
    ext {
      rotation_vector_start_keypoint_index: 0
      rotation_vector_end_keypoint_index: 1
      rotation_vector_target_angle_degrees: 90
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkfiltering__VisibilitySmoothingCalculator"
  calculator: "VisibilitySmoothingCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:unfiltered_auxiliary_landmarks"
  output_stream: "NORM_FILTERED_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__filtered_aux_visibility"
  options {
    ext {
      low_pass_filter {
        alpha: 0.1
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkfiltering__LandmarksSmoothingCalculator"
  calculator: "LandmarksSmoothingCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__filtered_aux_visibility"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_SIZE:image_size"
  input_stream: "OBJECT_SCALE_ROI:poselandmarkfiltering__roi"
  output_stream: "NORM_FILTERED_LANDMARKS:auxiliary_landmarks"
  options {
    ext {
      one_euro_filter {
        min_cutoff: 0.01
        beta: 10
        derivate_cutoff: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkstoroi__LandmarksToDetectionCalculator"
  calculator: "LandmarksToDetectionCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:auxiliary_landmarks"
  output_stream: "DETECTION:poselandmarkstoroi__detection"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkstoroi__AlignmentPointsRectsCalculator"
  calculator: "AlignmentPointsRectsCalculator"
  input_stream: "DETECTION:poselandmarkstoroi__detection"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_SIZE:image_size"
  output_stream: "NORM_RECT:poselandmarkstoroi__raw_roi"
  options {
    ext {
      rotation_vector_start_keypoint_index: 0
      rotation_vector_end_keypoint_index: 1
      rotation_vector_target_angle_degrees: 90
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkstoroi__RectTransformationCalculator"
  calculator: "RectTransformationCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECT:poselandmarkstoroi__raw_roi"
  input_stream: "IMAGE_SIZE:image_size"
  output_stream: "pose_rect_from_landmarks"
  options {
    ext {
      scale_x: 1.25
      scale_y: 1.25
      square_long: true
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__WorldLandmarkProjectionCalculator"
  calculator: "WorldLandmarkProjectionCalculator"
  input_stream: "LANDMARKS:poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_world_landmarks"
  input_stream: "NORM_RECT:pose_rect"
  output_stream: "LANDMARKS:unfiltered_world_landmarks"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__WarpAffineCalculator"
  calculator: "WarpAffineCalculator"
  input_stream: "IMAGE:poselandmarkbyroicpu__roi_segmentation_mask"
  input_stream: "MATRIX:poselandmarkbyroicpu__poselandmarksandsegmentationinverseprojection__inverse_transformation_matrix"
  input_stream: "OUTPUT_SIZE:poselandmarkbyroicpu__image_size"
  output_stream: "IMAGE:unfiltered_segmentation_mask"
  options {
    ext {
      border_mode: BORDER_ZERO
      gpu_origin: TOP_LEFT
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posesegmentationfiltering__PreviousLoopbackCalculator"
  calculator: "PreviousLoopbackCalculator"
  input_stream: "MAIN:unfiltered_segmentation_mask"
  input_stream: "LOOP:filtered_segmentation_mask"
  output_stream: "PREV_LOOP:posesegmentationfiltering__prev_filtered_segmentation_mask"
  input_stream_info {
    tag_index: "LOOP"
    back_edge: true
  }
}
node {
  name: "posesegmentationfiltering__GateCalculator"
  calculator: "GateCalculator"
  input_stream: "posesegmentationfiltering__prev_filtered_segmentation_mask"
  output_stream: "posesegmentationfiltering__gated_prev_filtered_segmentation_mask"
  input_side_packet: "ALLOW:smooth_segmentation"
  options {
    ext {
      allow: true
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "posesegmentationfiltering__SegmentationSmoothingCalculator"
  calculator: "SegmentationSmoothingCalculator"
  input_stream: "MASK:unfiltered_segmentation_mask"
  input_stream: "MASK_PREVIOUS:posesegmentationfiltering__gated_prev_filtered_segmentation_mask"
  output_stream: "MASK_SMOOTHED:filtered_segmentation_mask"
  options {
  }
}
node {
  calculator: "FromImageCalculator"
  input_stream: "IMAGE:filtered_segmentation_mask"
  output_stream: "IMAGE_CPU:segmentation_mask"
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__SwitchDemuxCalculator"
  calculator: "SwitchDemuxCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:unfiltered_pose_landmarks"
  output_stream: "C0__NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__c0__unfiltered_pose_landmarks"
  output_stream: "C1__NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__c1__unfiltered_pose_landmarks"
  input_side_packet: "ENABLE:smooth_landmarks"
  options {
    ext {
      enable: true
    }
  }
  input_stream_handler {
    input_stream_handler: "ImmediateInputStreamHandler"
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__VisibilitySmoothingCalculator_1"
  calculator: "VisibilitySmoothingCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__c0__unfiltered_pose_landmarks"
  output_stream: "NORM_FILTERED_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__c0__poselandmarkfiltering__filtered_visibility"
  options {
    ext {
      no_filter {
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__VisibilitySmoothingCalculator_2"
  calculator: "VisibilitySmoothingCalculator"
  input_stream: "NORM_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__c1__unfiltered_pose_landmarks"
  output_stream: "NORM_FILTERED_LANDMARKS:poselandmarkfiltering__switchcontainer_1__c1__poselandmarkfiltering__filtered_visibility"
  options {
    ext {
      low_pass_filter {
        alpha: 0.1
      }
    }
  }
}
......(could not paste all due to character limit)
  input_stream_handler {
    input_stream_handler: "ImmediateInputStreamHandler"
  }
}
input_stream: "IMAGE:image"
output_stream: "LANDMARKS:pose_landmarks"
output_stream: "WORLD_LANDMARKS:pose_world_landmarks"
output_stream: "SEGMENTATION_MASK:segmentation_mask"
output_stream: "DETECTION:pose_detection"
output_stream: "ROI_FROM_LANDMARKS:pose_rect_from_landmarks"
output_stream: "ROI_FROM_DETECTION:pose_rect_from_detection"
input_side_packet: "SMOOTH_LANDMARKS:smooth_landmarks"
input_side_packet: "ENABLE_SEGMENTATION:enable_segmentation"
input_side_packet: "SMOOTH_SEGMENTATION:smooth_segmentation"
input_side_packet: "MODEL_COMPLEXITY:model_complexity"
input_side_packet: "USE_PREV_LANDMARKS:use_prev_landmarks"
executor {
}
type: "PoseLandmarkCpu"
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing this exact same issue today and installing mediapipe-silicon and opencv-python in a **new 3.9.10 Python environment** did the trick. I think it might have something to do with the under-the-hood operation of mediapipe and the compiled version "media pipe-silicon" that prevents it from playing nicely with other Python distros.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me :(. I created a conda env with 3.9.10 but still the same error. `"mediapipe.CalculatorOptions" has no field named "ext".

[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:335] Error parsing text-format mediapipe.CalculatorGraphConfig: 22:9: Message type "mediapipe.CalculatorOptions" has no field named "ext".
`

Comment: This worked! I used miniforge instead of anaconda and python 3.10.4. Thank you!